# App Script how to read a form object passed through cloud function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm building a web app to take files from a web form and put them in a Google Drive folder. Upon submitting the form, I want to run a cloud function with google.script.run while passing through the form object as a parameter.

My question is how can I access the files in Code.gs after passing through the form object? I want to get the file names and maybe other data.
My code below:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <label for="FormControlFile">Select File:</label> 
      <input name="myFile" type="file" id="FormControlFile" multiple />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?!= include('script'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
const folderId = "my folder id";
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function include(fileName) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(fileName).getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  //formObject.files??
}
```

script.html:

```
<script>

  function preventFormSubmit() {
    const form = document.getElementById("myForm")
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit);

  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.uploadFiles(formObject);
  }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It should be `formObject.myFile` and it will be a `blob` object. However, I'm not sure whether multiple files/blobs are supported per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your HTML, I noticed that you use `multiple` at `<input name="myFile" type="file" id="FormControlFile" multiple />`. From this situation, I guessed that in your situation, multiple files might be uploaded.

In the current stage, unfortunately, `google.script.run` cannot parse multiple files from the input tag. So, in this case, it is required to parse the files on the Javascript side.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script: `Code.gs`

In this case, the function `uploadFiles` is modified.

```js
const folderId = "my folder id";
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function include(fileName) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(fileName).getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  if (formObject.length == 0) {
    return "No files";
  }
  return formObject.map(e => folder.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e)).getId());
}
```

##### HTML: `index.html`

This is not modified.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <label for="FormControlFile">Select File:</label> 
      <input name="myFile" type="file" id="FormControlFile" multiple />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?!= include('script'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### Javascript: `script.html`

In this case, the function `handleFormSubmit` is modified.

```html
<script>

  function preventFormSubmit() {
    const form = document.getElementById("myForm")
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit);

  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    Promise.all([...formObject.myFile.files].map(file => {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      return new Promise(r => {
        fr.onload = e => r([[...new Int8Array(e.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
    }))
      .then(obj => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(console.log).uploadFiles(obj));
  }

</script>
```

- When this modified script is used when you open the HTML multiple files are selected and click "Submit" button, and the files are uploaded to Google Drive. And, you can see the uploaded file IDs in the console.

#### Note:

- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: That worked great. I can manipulate the file and get its properties if I save createFile to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your script like so:

```
<script>
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    const form = document.getElementById("myForm"); 
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleFormSubmit(form); // pass your form object to your handler function
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit);

  function handleFormSubmit(formElement) {
    google.script.run.uploadFiles(formElement); // pass formElement to your `uploadFiles` function from the script. If all other parameters are passed correctly, this would work.
  }
</script>
```

In your `Code.gs` You can then get access to files in form element:

```
function uploadFiles(form) {
  var fileBlob = form.myFile;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your-folder-id');

  // fileBlob is an array of files if multiple attribute is set on the input
  for (var i = 0; i < fileBlob.length; i++) {
    var file = fileBlob[i];
    folder.createFile(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced my script with yours and got an error: "Failed due to illegal value in property: 0"

Comment: Use console.log and debugger to check where things are going wrong.

Comment: It's an error with this line: google.script.run.uploadFiles(formData); I referenced https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run and read under the Parameters section. Looks like certain data types aren't allowed. I'm not sure if FormData is one of the prohibited types it talks about

Comment: @Nick I checked it seems you can pass the form element directly I've edited the code try that.

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, here is working Google Apps Script code, to be put in file Code.gs, to upload file to Google Drive and get uploaded file name.

```
const folderId = "my folder id";
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function include(fileName) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(fileName).getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    var fileUrl = "";
    var fileName = "";
    if (formObject.myFile.length > 0) {
      var blob = formObject.myFile;
      var file = folder.createFile(blob);
      fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      fileName = file.getName();
    }
  } catch (error) {
      return error.toString();
  }
}
```